# Test if a named pipe binding is available or already in use

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, named-pipes

I have a simple WCF service that is used for cross app-domain communication in our app.

the service is exposed via a NamedPipeBinding, currently using a hard coded name:

var address = "net.pipe://localhost/app/log";

```
        NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.
        logServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(LogService));
        logServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ILogProvider), binding, address);

        logServiceHost.Open();
```

The problem is that this name is hardcoded and so another instance of our app cannot allocate a new named pipe (since the name is already taken).

Is it possible to check if a name is already taken, and if so allocate a different name?

Or are there other easier strategies for handling such a scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically trying to make 'multi-instance aware' services. Typical approach to doing that is to allow each service instance to announce it's existance. The best way to do that is to use add an announcement endpoint:

```
var discoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
discoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
logServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(discoveryBehavior);
logServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
logServiceHost.Open();
```

You can later on discover each instance of existing services in the network and take necessary steps to prevent endpoint URI collisions, if necessary.

You can read more about [WCF Auto Discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx) behavior via the link.